# infinite integral defining Bessel functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Landau in the first equation of [Über die Gitterpunkte in einem Kreise](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01203524) uses the following formula for the Bessel function of the first kind:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{1-\infty}^{1+i\infty} \frac{\mathrm e^{As-B/s}}{s^4} \, \mathrm d s= (A/B)^{3/2} J_3(2 \sqrt{AB}))
$$ valid for all $A,B>0$.

Does anyone know of a reference or a proof of that? Since Landau gives no reference or hint I imagine it is either well-known or completely trivial.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the variable in the integral $s=kz$, where $k=\sqrt{B/A}$.
You obtain
$$\left(A/B\right)^{3/2}
\int \frac{\exp{\sqrt{AB}\left(z-1/z\right)}}{z^4}dz.$$
Then deform the contour of integration from the vertical line
to $|z|=1$, this is possible since the real part of
$(z-1/z)$ is bounded in a simply connected region which contains both contours.

And finally refer to the well known generating function
for Bessel functions
$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)z^n=\exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\left(z-1/z\right)\right).$$
Combined with Laurent's theorem this implies
that our integral is $J_3(2\sqrt{AB})$.

Comment: I have a silly question: one ends up with     $$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} J_n(2\sqrt{AB}) \int_{1-i \infty}^{1+i \infty} \frac{z^n}{z^4}\mathrm d z.$$ I think you are implying that the integrals vanish when $n\neq 3$. But how is that possible? for example, when $n=4$ isn't the integral just the integral of a constant function over an infinite line? I am sorry for I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I do not understand the formula you wrote. What does it mean? (there is no equality sign). Where does it come from? It makes to sense because all integrals with $n>2$ diverge.